# Using datePickerDialog when i selected date the value of month is coming unexpected

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android programming and when i print date in logcat proper date is coming,but when showing in editText unexpected value of month is coming.
like when i selected january the value of month is coming as 31. 
Here is my code:

```
private void setDateTimeField()
{
    e2.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);

    Calendar newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new OnDateSetListener()
    {

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
        {
            Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
            //Log.e("Date",newDate+"");
            newDate.set(year, monthOfYear+1, dayOfMonth);
            Log.e("Year:",year+"/month:"+(monthOfYear+1)+"/date:"+dayOfMonth);
            Log.e("Date:",newDate+"");
            e2.setText(dateFormat.format(newDate.getTime()));
        }

    },newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),(newCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)),
    newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));



}
@Override
public void onFocusChange(View arg0, boolean arg1) {
    if(arg0 == e2)
    {
        datePickerDialog.show();
    } 

}
```

Comment: Did you specify a dateFormat?

Comment: Yes,I do have specified that as : dateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yy",Locale.US);
  setDateTimeField();